# how to solve Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I write a PDO class . This is my PDO class.

```
class Database {
     private $host = DB_HOST;
     private $user = DB_USER;
     private $pass = DB_PASS;
     private $dbname = DB_NAME;

     private $dbh;
     private $error;
     private $stmt;

     public function __construct() {
        //set DNS
        $dns = 'mysql:host'. $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

        //set option
        $option = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PRESISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODER_EXCEPTION

        );

         //create a new PDO instance
         try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dns,$this->user,$this->password,$option);
         } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
         }

         public function query($query) {
            $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
         }

        public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
             if(is_null($type)) {
                switch(TRUE) {
                    case is_int($value) :
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        break;
                    case is_bool($value) :
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;
                    case is_null($value) :
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;
                    default :
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }
            $this->stmt->bindValue($param,$value,$type);
        }

        public function execute() {
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        }

        public function resultset() {
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }

        public function single() {
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }

        public function rowCount() {
            return $this->stmt->rowCount();
        }

        public function lastInsertId() {
            return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it the following error is occurs :

error message is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in
C:\xampp\htdocs\php\talkingspace\lib\Database.php on line 32
```

line 32 has follwing code :

```
public function query($query) {
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}
```

I can not figure out the problem. any help would be great for me.

thanks

Comment: Close the function `__construct()` with `}` Proper code indentation would give you an idea why its happening.

Comment: Hmmm PDO is already an abstraction layer that allows you to hook into various different database servers... why are you abstracting that abstraction layer anyway?

Comment: `$pass = DB_PASS;` <- Every property needs a visibility

Comment: you have declared `$dsn = 'mysql:host'. $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;` but you used undeclared variable `$dns` `$this->dbh = new PDO($dns,$this->user,$this->password,$option);`

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake $pass property is private. @Rizier123

Comment: I have corrected it but error  is sill happening. @HalayemAnis

Comment: @NitolBiswas : the answer of your problem was given by " Abhik Chakraborty", did you check it ?

Comment: thank you @AbhikChakraborty problem is solved:)

Comment: thank you @HalayemAnis problem is solved:)

Comment: thanks to the humain parser @AbhikChakraborty :)